# Android app purchase - click on the pay button second time - exception

Tags: android

I have an issue in google app purchase,
Scenario is when user clicks purchase button launch the google purchase popup window, then user click hardware back button to cancel it, then second time when we click on the payment button again, it say error

Code is :

```
  public void launchPayment() {
    try {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        int responseCode = buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        String purchaseData = buyIntentBundle.getString("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            if (responseCode == 7) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "You already owned this product", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                updatePayOptions();
                paymentCallBack.paidCallBack(0);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Please sign in with your gmail account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            return;
        }

        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                Integer.valueOf(0));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

result code

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", -1);
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        ArrayList<String> itemList = data.getStringArrayListExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                if (sku.equalsIgnoreCase(productId)) {
                    updatePayOptions();
                    paymentCallBack.paidCallBack(0);
                }
                //  alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice,
                // adve//nturer!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            paymentCallBack.paidCallBack(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Error is this :

```
     /? W/System.err: android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner(Activity.java:4149)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4120)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4087)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at com.pearson.skillsusa.ui.WelcomeActivity.launchPayment(WelcomeActivity.java:266)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at com.pearson.skillsusa.ui.fragments.WelcomeFragment$3.onClick(WelcomeFragment.java:90)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
01-18 15:08:20.906 16465-16465/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

As far as i trace this error in this place `startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                    1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                    Integer.valueOf(0));`

then second time popup window doesnt come

Any idea? could please suggest any solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the coding part of it but I think you should remove pending intent when you press the cancel button

Comment: i have tried this way  `PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, data, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel(); `   no luck same error

Comment: See this link it will clear things up a bit 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.SendIntentException.html